# Java Enum and managing state

Tags: java, spring, enums

I want to use and Enumeration type to represent feature flags in my application. The enumeration type has a state and a description. I want to be able do something like the following in my code;

```
FeatureFlag.FANCYFEATURE.isActive()
```

The isActive() method would then call out to a service class connecting to a database to fetch the features state.

However in my spring application its not possible inject a bean into an Enum as the Enum type is static.

Can someone recommend a clean way to so this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following statement should tell you something is wrong

> The isActive() method would then call out to a service class
>   connecting to a database to fetch the features state

If you are fetching the state, we can assume it might be different at different times, ie. not a constant. Don't use `enum` for this.

And if you did, to answer

> Can someone recommend a clean way to so this?

There is no way to inject beans into it, like you said.

Comment: Exactly... sounds like a misuse of enum here.

Answer (score 3):

By all means use an `enum` for a list of features but please don't use the `enum` for mutable state.

You would be better off using a `EnumMap<Enum,State>` structure to store mutable state against an `enum`.